# Java - Delete directory using File.deleteOnExit()

Tags: java, file-io

I am learning how to use `deleteOnExit()` to delete a directory. As far as I know, it can only delete a folder when it is empty. So below is the method that recursively wiping the child files / folders, then eventually the root.

```
static void deleteFile(File path){
    if (!path.exists()) return;
    path.deleteOnExit();
}


static void deleteFolder(File path){
    if (!path.exists()) return;

    //clean children
    for (File f : path.listFiles()){
        if (f.isDirectory()){
            deleteFolder(f);
        }
        else{
            deleteFile(f);
        }
    }

    //clean root
    path.deleteOnExit();
}
```

And this is a folder sample structure & how I call the method

```
//folder structure
parent_folder
|---child_folder
    |---child2_file
|--child_file

//calling method
Path path = Path.of("src/p - Copy");
deleteFolder(path.toFile());
```

The sample structure result is below. I seems to me that only child files get deleted. Note that if I re-run the code for several times, `child_folder` eventually get deleted (since this time `child2_folder` is removed), then `parent_folder`.

```
parent_folder
|---child_folder
```

Nevertheless inside `deleteFolder` method, if I swap the two section as  first, then . The whole directory `parent_folder` is wiped out as desired.

```
//clean root
path.deleteOnExit();

//clean children
for (File f : path.listFiles()){
    if (f.isDirectory()){
        deleteFolder(f);
    }
    else{
        deleteFile(f);
    }
}
```

What caused this method to behave in such a reversed order?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: JavaDocs stated `Files (or directories) are deleted in the reverse order that they are registered.`. So if you call clean root with deleteOnExit() at last, it will execute first.

Comment: To fix that, put the `path.deleteOnExit();` before doing the recursion.

Comment: @PeterMmm Hm so I can imagine the deleting order behaving like a stack. You have any idea they make it work in reverse order?

Comment: Probably this method is meant for temporary files and directories: you create a directory and immediately mark it as `deleteOnExit()`. Then you create a file in that directory and also immediately mark it as `deleteOnExit()`. For this case deleting them in reverse order is the correct way to do.

Comment: You should avoid using `deleteOnExit()` and delete the files immediately after use instead. And use NIO instead of this old API, as [`Files.delete(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) will tell you about the reason when it fails.